# What is the purpose of duplicated Segments in ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart?

Tags: experience-analytics, sitecore-rocks

I am designing Experience Analytics report via Sitecore Rocks.

Could anyone please explain to me the purpose of duplicated segments as shown in the following picture? Some can be used to display result while some can't.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicated segment item is expected behavior in Sitecore 9 as it has introduced **FlexibleDimension**.

It is written at the improvement section in the [release note of Sitecore 9 Initial Release](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes).

> *“​Flexible dimensions give Sitecore the ability to record domain specific metrics. The previous approach to dimensions is still available, but will be deprecated in a future version of Sitecore.​”*

In Content Editor, each item under *Pages* and *Visits* (under `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions`) is all “duplicated”, one is based on **Dimension** template and one is based on **FlexibleDimension** template.

This information can be easily identified in Sitecore Rocks by hovering mouse pointer over each Segment item.

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal, I don't have duplicates in my instance at 8.2u5 with Rocks. Are they only duplicate in rocks and not in Sitecore? If not, I would suspect something being of with your (search)indexing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this at your end. After further investigation, it turns out that they actually come from different templates. One is based on _Dimension_ whereas another is based on _FlexibleDimension_. I am using Sitecore 9.0.0 (rev. 171002).